# I need made a combinatorial analysis on an array and generate a number with this

Tags: arrays, c, math

Hi i am an amateur in programing, but i propose me to getting better and because that i start to solve problems in online judges and i don't know how to do a combinatorial analysis, i found some similar question but i can't apply to my code, if you are able to explain me how to do it, i will be incredibly grateful.
so here is the full text of the problem, translated of Portuguese to English. At end is my code.
To prove her scientific skills Princess Bubblegum learned to program using BMO (The best computer in the Candy kingdom) and like every programmer she fell in love with binary numbers.

Because of her addiction to binary numbers she loves decimal numbers that look like a binary number (i.e. a decimal number that contains only digits 0 and 1, for example 101) so given a decimal number N she wants to find a multiple of that number that looks like a number binary, but for some numbers it was taking a long time to find that multiple, even with the help of BMO. Because of her problem-solving addiction, she wasn't doing anything until she found this multiple. Perfect situation for the Earl of Lemongrab, who has taken over the Candy Kingdom. As Finn and Jake, the heroes of the Candy kingdom, can't do anything against the Count and know nothing about multiples, they asked to find the multiples and thus save the kingdom.

Prohibited
The input contains up to 2*10^5 lines, each line with an integer N (0 < N < 10^12), the number Princess Bubblegum wants to find the multiple M (M != 0), this number must be smaller than 10^12, otherwise it doesn't fit in the BMO architecture.

Exit
Print a single integer per line, if there are multiple multiples print the smallest one. If there is no solution print -1

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() // normal ways works fine but i have to do it faster, time limit is 2s//
//doing 11 fors works to but its have same tle problem//
{
long long int n, R, num, res, expo;
int b = 0, dig[11] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, E=0, an, anmax = 1024, reseter, cob, casa;

while (E < 200000)
{
  E++;
  num = 0;
  scanf("%lld", &n); //I have to read a decimal number and from that found the smaller multiple number that is similar to a binary number, and cannot be 0//
  res=n%10;
  if ((res==1) || (res==0)) // in case the read number is already similar to binary, this works fine//
  { b=1;
    for ( num=n;((num>0) && (b==1)); num=num/10)
    {
      res=num%10;
      if ((res==1) || (res==0)){
      b=1;
      R=n;
      }else
      {
        b=0;
        R=-1;
      }
      
    }
    
    
  }else{
  if ((n > 0) && (n < 1000000000000))
  {
    if (n < 500000000000)
    {
      num = n;
      for (expo = -1; num >= 1; expo++, num = num / 10)//so expo is a varieble to found the smaller house of input to made a number, its just for reduce cycles//
      {
        res = num % 10;
      }
      if (res > 1)
      {
        expo = expo + 1;
      }
      dig[expo] = 1;
      R = ((dig[11] * 100000000000) + (dig[10] * 10000000000) + (dig[9] * 1000000000) + (dig[8] * 100000000) + (dig[7] * 10000000) + (dig[6] * 1000000) + (dig[5] * 100000) + (dig[4] * 10000) + (dig[3] * 1000) + (dig[2] * 100) + (dig[1] * 10) + (dig[0] * 1));
      for (dig[expo] = 1; ((expo < 11) && (b == 0)); expo++)//// 1 is fixed value until no one of numbers is divisible//
      {
        anmax = pow(2, expo);//forget this line//
        dig[expo] = 1;
        for (casa = 0; ((casa < expo) && (b == 0)); casa++)//here is my problem i dont know how to alternate all values that can be ninary// 
        { //this is my original idea to solve but this don't generate all possible values// 
          for (cob = 0; ((cob < 2) && (b == 0)); cob++)
          {
            dig[casa] = cob;
            R = ((dig[11] * 100000000000) + (dig[10] * 10000000000) + (dig[9] * 1000000000) + (dig[8] * 100000000) + (dig[7] * 10000000) + (dig[6] * 1000000) + (dig[5] * 100000) + (dig[4] * 10000) + (dig[3] * 1000) + (dig[2] * 100) + (dig[1] * 10) + (dig[0] * 1));
            if ((R % n) == 0)
            {
              b = 1;
            }
            
            
          }
        }
        if ((cob == 2) || (b==1))
        {
          for (reseter = expo; reseter >= 0; reseter--)//it works fine is just to start all values with 0 before its repeats//
          {
            dig[reseter] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      R = -1;
    }
    if((R==11111111111) && ((n!=21649) || (n!=513239))){
        R=-1; //its not important//
    }
  }else
  {
    R=-1;
  }
  
  }
  // reset para proximos valores//
  b = 0;
  printf("%lld\n", R);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the problem is that the code isn't fast enough, well that's all part of the problem you have to solve. Bear in mind that online judge sites aren't good learning resources. They are amusements for people who already code, like crosswords are fun things for people who know language well.

Comment: ... I see you have input as an integer, and then extract each digit. Why not input as a string? There is a thinking trap among beginners that a "number" must be `int` type or `long` type (and that "character" must be `char` type).

Comment: A problem is `dig[9] * 1000000000`: `dig[9]` is an `int`, `1000000000` is also an `int`, so the result will also be an `int`, but if `dig[9] > 2` the result will not fit in an `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, when i inicialize to make this code i didn't know how to use char, so i use a long int instead

Comment: @mch it's a problem even if R is a long int?

Comment: There is no `R` in `dig[9] * 1000000000`, so it is unrelated to the type of `R`. The assignment to `R` is okay, the problem is the intermediate result, which is still in the smaller type, not in the result type.